# "Close" Button of programmatically created Excel doesn't kill the process Excel.exe

Tags: vb.net, winforms, excel, interop

Good day everyone, I've got a rough question for you.

I've programatically created an excel document using Interop.Excel and when I close it programmatically process EXCEL.EXE has been killed. BUT, when I close the document by clicking "Close" button the process is being alive. Does anyone know what should I release in my code to make my application works correctly? And, btw, why does it might happen?

Comment: This is by design.  If that would work, your program will crash since the references you have to interfaces like Application would no longer work.  So Excel complies, closes its user interface and *keeps running*.  It won't exit until the references you created are garbage collected.  That doesn't happen instantly of course.  Just keep doing useful work.  GC.Collect() if this is really important for some reason.  It shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the Application using interop while coding:

For example:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();   
 Document doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\\DocWord.docx");
 doc.Activate();

 //Do some stuff

 //Close document
   doc.Close();

 //Close application!

    app.Quit();
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I didn't choose right words..You didn't catch me. I want to close Excel document by clicking X button in the document. And also this document was created programmatically.

Comment: You should close the application after you create it programmatically. That EXCEL.exe application not being closed when you hit X, was created by the application. When you use interop office classes they start Word.exe, Excel.exe when creating documents.

Comment: Oookay..that's pretty weird for me. I have old vb6 code and closing excel by "X" causes process to kill. However in vb.net you say it can't be killed by clicking "X"...Maybe there is some other reason, do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Closing the final document in Excel does not close Excel. You can verify this yourself by opening Excel in the normal way and File -> Close. This is by design and standard for any application following the Multiple Document Interface (MDI) model.

To exit the process, use Application.Quit where Application is an instance of the Excel application object.

Comment: No-no, I mean close the document by clicking an X button, not hust File -> Close. When I click X button process Excel.exe is killed immediately.